# how to use if else in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, label

I am new to flutter and i don't know how to change the color of label using if-else statement. basically, This statement giving me error.

```
selectedItemColor:_selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.cyan: Colors.grey,
    **_selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.cyan: Colors.grey,**
```

I am using this in Bottom navigation bar and if I use title, flutter didn't accept.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar( onTap: _onItemTapped, items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: _selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.cyan: Colors.grey,), label: 'Home'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.ballot, color: _selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.cyan: Colors.grey,), label: 'Services'),
      ],
      selectedItemColor:_selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.cyan: Colors.grey,
        _selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.cyan: Colors.grey,
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Noto Sans TC',
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: false,
        backgroundColor: HexColor('#09B9B6'),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        children: _Screens,
        onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called ternary operator – `? :`. And according to your current logic you should use this code:

```dart
selectedItemColor: _selectedIndex == 0 || _selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.cyan : Colors.grey
```

But I don't see any reason to use this logic for setting `selectedItemColor` of `BottomNavigationBar`. It will be set to selected item automatically, so you can just use `selectedItemColor: Colors.cyan` instead.

Comment: but this is giving me an error that you are not returning a valid widget in if-else statement like this **Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1290 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  BottomNavigationBar file:///C:/Users/DELL/AndroidStudioProjects/gigoclean/lib/pages/location.dart:52:28**

Comment: I don't see any resons causing this error in your current code. Could you please add full `location.dart` file and full error log to your answer?

Comment: i solved that error. i was not making a different file for BottomNavigationBar. i dont have basic knowledge of BottomNavigationBar and still facing other errors

Answer (score 0):

With `selectedItemColor:_selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.cyan: Colors.grey,` you tell Dart to assign the Value `Colors.cyan` or  `Colors.grey` to the named argument `selectedItemColor`. However the `_selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.cyan: Colors.grey` is misplaced there.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar( onTap: _onItemTapped, items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: _selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.cyan: Colors.grey,), label: 'Home'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.ballot, color: _selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.cyan: Colors.grey,), label: 'Services'),
      ],
      selectedItemColor:(_selectedIndex == 0||_selectedIndex == 1) ? Colors.cyan: Colors.grey,
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Noto Sans TC',
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: false,
        backgroundColor: HexColor('#09B9B6'),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        children: _Screens,
        onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This will make the Navigation Bar Cyan when _selectedIndex is 0 or 1.